# Multi word search on multiple columns Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony1

I am trying to craft a multiword search that will query multiple columns in a table. My code works great thus far for a single column, but as you can imagine using it for more then one column becomes an issue.

If I add `orWhere` it won't work, and I don't really want to create more for loops because it will become quite cumbersome. Any Ideas?

```
$query = $request->getParameter("article-search");
$keywords = explode(" ", $query);

for( $i = 1; $i <= count( $keywords ); $i++ ){
    $q->addWhere("a.title LIKE ?", "%" . $keywords[$i - 1] . "%");
}
```

Comment: I've done something like this in the past as a Class that I reuse. It's too big to post here, but I'll explain. Start building just a "string" variable, don't try to build with Database Merhods. You'll have several loops to work out. First, when searching across multiple columns, you'll add LIKE's with "OR"s between them. The there's the words, which you will split; recommend using preg_split() for more control. For each word, you'll want to limit the search, so use "AND"s between them. Keep in mind that you might also have multiple parameters/conditions and even types (string,int,date).

Answer (score 2):

I just did it like this.. Maybe it helps somebody..

```
$now = "some other parameter";

$parts = explode(" ",trim($searchtext));
$clauses=array();
// static paramtter setted here
$parameters = array(
    ':now' => $now
);

$i = 0;
foreach ($parts as $part){
    // for every word make new search query and parameter
    $parameters[":param".$i] = "%".$part."%";
    if($i == 0){
        $clauses  = "v.description LIKE :param".$i." OR v.name LIKE :param".$i." OR v.sale LIKE :param".$i;
    } else {
        $clauses .= " OR v.description LIKE :param".$i." OR v.name LIKE :param".$i." OR v.sale LIKE :param".$i;
    }
    $i ++;
}

$qb->select('v')
    ->from('MyBundle\Entity\Voucher', 'v')
    ->where('v.date_start <= :now')
    ->andWhere('v.date_end >= :now')

    ->andWhere($clauses)
    ->setParameters($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would write this as a query that looks something like the following:

```
$query = "`where column like '%$keywordOne%' or column like '%keywordTwo%'`";
```

Though I'm not sure how you implement that with the query-building tool you have there.

Here's a quick example that might help build the where portion of the query using the array of keywords you have:

```
<?php
$keywords = array("bing", "bang", "jump");

$query_start = 'where colummName';
$like_portion = "like '%" . implode("%' or columnName like '%", $keywords) . "%'";

if(sizeof($keywords) > 0) {
    echo "`$query_start $like_portion`";
} else {
    // No keywords
}
?>
```

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify here

Comment: I like where your idea is going, ill keep you posted :)

Comment: That doesn't address the issue. The issue was multiple terms against multiple columns.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can consider using "union"? Also, for such complex queries, I would use native SQL instead of ORM practice.